# Trouble configuring Hibernate 4 with MySQL 5.1

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, junit

Does anyone have an example of a successful hibernate.cfg.xml configuration file where they use Hibernate 4 and MySQL 5.1?  I have a Maven (v3.0.3) web project and when I run my JUnit test, the test fails with the exception, even though the table, USERS, exists ...

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @org.hibernate.annotations.Table references an unknown table: USERS
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:875)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3406)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3360)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1334)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1724)
    at com.myco.eventmaven.dao.UsersDaoImpl.&lt;init&gt;(UsersDaoImpl.java:27)
    at com.myco.eventmaven.dao.UsersDaoImplTest.setUpStaticVars(UsersDaoImplTest.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml file ...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eventmaven</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">eventmaven</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

<mapping class="com.myco.eventmaven.domain.Registration" />

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What is curious is that i get the same exception even if I change the URL, username, or password to an absolutely incorrect value.  Here is the declaration of the class I'm trying to bind to ...

```
package com.myco.eventmaven.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(appliesTo = "USERS")
public class Registration implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
Integer id;

@Column(name = "USERNAME")
private String userName;
@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 4, max = 20)
@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password;
@NotEmpty
private String confirmPassword;
@NotEmpty
private String salt;
@NotEmpty
@Email
@Column(name = "EMAIL")
private String email;
@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
private String lastName;

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
    this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
}

public String getConfirmPassword() {
    return confirmPassword;
}

public String getSalt() {
    return salt;
}

public void setSalt(String salt) {
    this.salt = salt;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

}
```

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: 1) Are you using unix, and 2) does it work outside JUnit / when you run the tests from Eclipse / in your webapp, i.e. is the problem just maven, or is it everywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The table does exist, but the annotation I was using was wrong.  I needed to use the annotation

```
@Table(name = "USERS")
```

in which @Table was imported from import javax.persistence.Table;.  Before @Table was imported from an org.hibernate package and that was messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have problem with connection - you log is clear : there is no table USERS.
Why use @Table(appliesTo ="USERS") in another file, at least it is better to define it before its entity definition.

You dont have table USERS included in hibernate mapping file.

[@Table API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.4/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Table.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may be having problems with case sensitivity, using certain operating systems, table names can be case sensitive in MySQL. From [8.2.2. Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) (my emphasis):

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data
>   directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one
>   file within the database directory (and possibly more, depending on
>   the storage engine). Triggers also correspond to files. Consequently,
>   the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part
>   in the case sensitivity of database, table, and trigger names. **This
>   means such names are not case sensitive in Windows, but are case
>   sensitive in most varieties of Unix.** One notable exception is Mac OS
>   X, which is Unix-based but uses a default file system type (HFS+) that
>   is not case sensitive. However, Mac OS X also supports UFS volumes,
>   which are case sensitive just as on any Unix. See Section 1.8.4,
>   “MySQL Extensions to Standard SQL”. The `lower_case_table_names`
>   system variable also affects how the server handles identifier case
>   sensitivity.

So check the table names, check how they were initially created. The linked page has a number of options on how to deal with this problem.